# Is grunt-contrib-requirejs meant to replace the standard RequireJS config file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs

I'm trying to implement RequireJS along with GruntJS for a project. So far I am struggling to understand what each part is responsible for and doing. I got Grunt doing some optimizing at some point, but it seems like it's not loading files based on my config.js file.

How is using Grunt supposed to change my implementation of RequireJS? Some perspective would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to serve the RequireJS config file to the client as usual. `grunt-contrib-requirejs` just makes the r.js optimizer function into a GruntJS task so you don't have to do `node r.js -o name=main out=main.min.js` every time you want to concatenate and minify all your RequireJS files, and also so you can integrate it into your other Grunt tasks.